# Extracting XML by ignoring certain nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml

Input XML:

```
<Hierarchy><Relation>
        <Child>
        <Name>XYZ</Name>
        <Age>10</Age>
        </Child>
        <IsEldest>True</IsEldest>
        </Relation>
        <Relation>
        <Child>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Age>5</Age>
        </Child>
        </Relation>
        <Relation>
        <Child>
        <Name>PQR</Name>
        <Age>3</Age>
        </Child>
        </Relation></Hierarchy>
```

Expected Result:

```
          <Relation>
        <Child>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Age>5</Age>
        </Child>
        </Relation>
        <Relation>
        <Child>
        <Name>PQR</Name>
        <Age>3</Age>
        </Child>
        </Relation>
```

How can we retrieve the expected result using sql server in a single sql xml query. 
The  node which does not have the IsEldest tag should be extracted.
There is an option of deleting the Relation tag with IsEldes node using @xml.modify. But any other method of extracting the required xml?

Comment: Might there be an occurance of `<IsEldest>True</IsEldest>` with a value other than `True`? What should happen in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@xml.query('//Relation[not(IsEldest[1]="True")]')
```

Comment: I completely misunderstood this question +1 from my side!

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, this works. I was trying with @xml.query('//Relation[(IsEldest[1]!="True")]') and obviously it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

You might use an `XQuery` expression with `FLWOR` approach:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Hierarchy>
  <Relation>
    <Child>
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
      <Age>10</Age>
    </Child>
    <IsEldest>True</IsEldest>
  </Relation>
  <Relation>
    <Child>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <Age>5</Age>
    </Child>
  </Relation>
  <Relation>
    <Child>
      <Name>PQR</Name>
      <Age>3</Age>
    </Child>
  </Relation>
</Hierarchy>';
```

--The query (edited according to TT.'s comment)

```
SELECT @xml.query
(N'
    <Relation>
    {
    for $c in /Hierarchy/Relation[not(IsEldest[1]="True")]/Child
    return $c
    }
    </Relation>
');
```

The result

```
<Relation>
  <Child>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Age>5</Age>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Name>PQR</Name>
    <Age>3</Age>
  </Child>
</Relation>
```